# Looking for input on how to best organize my firebase collection based on an array property

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

This is a problem I'm facing on multiple projects. Say I have a collection of documents on a firebase database that looks like this:

[image]

Now, say I need to show multiple of these documents on my app in a way that they are organized by category, for example, an object that contains each category and inside the documents that include it.

I'm not sure where to go for a solution. Should I get all documents and filter them on the client side? Seems like that could be performance heavy and hard to implement.

Should I use a nested collection instead of an array? I would appreciate some keywords or links so that I can further investigate if and how this is the best practice approach.

Am I way off and there's a better solution that I'm not seeing?

Comment: I don't understand what your requirement is.  Are you trying to build a display that involves every document in a collection organized by the contents of their `categories` array?

Comment: I want to sort my collection based on its categories, so that I can show them that way on my front end. Like how netflix, spotify, etc does it

Comment: I don't use either of those services.  Could you edit the question to be clear about what you're trying to build?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure how to be clearer, I mean you said it on your comment after your edit. Simply sort by category, like pretty much every app and website does. I thank you for your time but it feels like you're intentionally misunderstanding the question

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to build a display that involves every document in a collection, you might as well just query for all of them and organize them on the client.  It'll almost certainly be faster than trying to make multiple queries for documents that might overlap in each query.  Without knowing more about how much data you actually have, there's not much else that can be said.  If you're still worried about performance at this point, you're probably going down the route of premature optimization - unless you have a measurable performance problem with actual data, I wouldn't put effort into designing something special.